# pop the keys or elements out of the array

Tags: php, cakephp

Please read the comments in the code. I need to pop the elements that match certain criteria

```
$popthisarray= array(12, 34);


main array

array
    0
    array
        'id' => int 12

    1
    array
        'id' => int 1456

    2
    array
        'id' => int 34

    3
    array
        'id' => int 534
```

I need to pop the elements from the main array that are in $popthisarray
I have

```
foreach($mainarray as $myarray){

// $myid will be either 12 0r 34

    if(in_array($my['id'],$mainarray)){

        //here I need to take the element out of main array
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would like to remove all elements of the `$mainarray`, that have `id` value in the `$popthisarray` ?

```
foreach($mainarray as $k => $my) {
    if(in_array($my['id'], $popthisarray)) {
        unset($mainarray[$k]);
    }
}
```

If you wish to reorganise keys, use `array_values`:

```
$mainarray = array_values($mainarray);
```

Comment: that unset the key but then I loose the keys like in this case my index 0 and 10 is gone so it starts from 1 etc

Comment: I added key reset to the answer.